# How to find out if running script/command as root/sudo using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, centos

I am following https://lifehacker.com/add-a-handy-separator-between-commands-in-your-terminal-5840450 to create a nice separator between commands in the terminal in Linux. Specifically, CentOS 8.

I am trying to modify the script to output the username of the user who ran the command.

[Here](https://github.com/Ajhad1/emilis-config/blob/master/.bash_ps1) is what I came up with.

```
# Fill with minuses
# (this is recalculated every time the prompt is shown in function prompt_command):
fill="--- "

reset_style='\[\033[00m\]'
if [ -z "$VIM" ];
then status_style=$reset_style'\[\033[0;90m\]' # gray color; use 0;37m for lighter color
else status_style=$reset_style'\[\033[0;90;107m\]'
fi
prompt_style=$reset_style
command_style=$reset_style'\[\033[1;29m\]' # bold black
# Prompt variable:

OLD_PS1="$PS1"
PS1="$status_style"'$fill $USER \t\n'"$prompt_style$OLD_PS1$command_style"

# Reset color for command output
# (this one is invoked every time before a command is executed):
trap 'echo -ne "\e[0m"' DEBUG


function prompt_command {

    # create a $fill of all screen width minus the time string and a space and USER and a space:
    let fillsize=${COLUMNS}-10-${#USER}
    fill=""
    while [ "$fillsize" -gt "0" ]
    do
        fill="-${fill}" # fill with underscores to work on 
        let fillsize=${fillsize}-1
    done

    # If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
    case "$TERM" in
    xterm*|rxvt*)
        bname=`basename "${PWD/$HOME/~}"`
        echo -ne "\033]0;${bname}: ${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD/$HOME/~}\007"
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
    esac

}
PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_command
```

Line 15 added " " and `$USER` to what is generated.

Line 25 changed to include an extra space and the length of the variable `$USER`

It looks just like I want it to.

[image: Terminal Screenshot]

But, I would like to update the code to output if I ran a command as `sudo` or not. 
Ideally, it would change the name to root or whatever the root user name is.

I have tried several things, mainly I tried using `whoami` but this always returns my username not root. 
If I run `sudo whoami` I get root but not from the script.
I also tried `EUID` No dice.

At this point, I have left the code in working condition with the `$USER` reference but I am willing to change it to whatever it needs to be.

### Solution provided by [u/pLumo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/590493/415883)

> Solution Limitations:
>
> - There are cases not covered, for example sudo --user=some_user .... I think it's fairly easy to further enhance the awk script.
> - As it relies on the history, it won't work with commands you do not have in history, e.g. when using HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth and issue a command with a space in front.

```
# Fill with minuses
# (this is recalculated every time the prompt is shown in function prompt_command):
fill="--- "

reset_style='\[\033[00m\]'
if [ -z "$VIM" ];
then status_style=$reset_style'\[\033[0;90m\]' # gray color; use 0;37m for lighter color
else status_style=$reset_style'\[\033[0;90;107m\]'
fi
prompt_style=$reset_style
command_style=$reset_style'\[\033[1;29m\]' # bold black
# Prompt variable:

OLD_PS1="$PS1"
PS1="$status_style"'$fill $name \t\n'"$prompt_style$OLD_PS1$command_style"

# Reset color for command output
# (this one is invoked every time before a command is executed):
trap 'echo -ne "\e[0m"' DEBUG


function prompt_command {

    # create a $fill of all screen width minus the time string and a space and USER and a space:
    name=$(fc -l -1 | awk -v u="$USER" '{if ($2=="sudo") { if ($3=="-u") u=$4; else u="root"; }; printf "%s",u}')
    let fillsize=${COLUMNS}-10-${#name}
    fill=""
    while [ "$fillsize" -gt "0" ]
    do
        fill="-${fill}" # fill with underscores to work on 
        let fillsize=${fillsize}-1
    done

    # If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
    case "$TERM" in
    xterm*|rxvt*)
        bname=`basename "${PWD/$HOME/~}"`
        echo -ne "\033]0;${bname}: ${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD/$HOME/~}\007"
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
    esac

}
PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_command
```

[image: Terminal Output - Solution]

Comment: (classic example) -- on your system does `/bin/id -u` yield different results with/without sudo?

Comment: Yes, it does. 
Running `/bin/id -u` returns `1000` my id.
Running `sudo /bin/id -u` returns `0` the root id.

Comment: OK, thought so; I'll update the answer section. Please mark as up-vote / accepted as you can.

Comment: If it works I will mark it as the solution. But, I might have already tried it previously and it did not work.

Comment: As I thought. This does not work. If I run it from the CLI then it outputs as I stated. The code I am using is being run by `.bashrc` not by me in the CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `prompt_command` you don't know which user ran the last command. `prompt_command` is always run by your normal users session.

As a workaround. you can read and parse the `history`.

E.g.: Using `fc -l -1` to print the last command, `awk ...` to parse it.

---

In line `#15` change `$USER` to `$name`

In line `#23` , add this:

```
name=$(fc -l -1 | awk -v u="$USER" '{if ($2=="sudo") { if ($3=="-u") u=$4; else u="root"; }; printf "%s",u}')
```

In line `#25`, change `${#USER}` to `${#name}`

---

This will print `root` for `sudo some command` and `some_user` for `sudo -u some_user some command`.

But please note, that this solution has some limitations:

- There are cases not covered, for example  `sudo --user=some_user ...`. I think it's fairly easy to further enhance the `awk` script.
- As it relies on the `history`, it won't work with commands you do not have in `history`, e.g. when using `HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth` and issue a command with a space in front.

Comment: I will try this and report back.
Just to clarify, this will return my user name when I am not using `sudo` and return `root` when using `sudo`?

Comment: I tried it and it seems to be working. Thank you so much. Any ideas on how to pull the other user names when using `sudo -u some_user some command`

Comment: Added that. It's still not failsafe, e.g. this is not covered `--user=user`. I think it's fairly easy to further enhance the awk script.

Comment: Thank you so much. 
You further clarification was what I needed as I am a novice and I did not understand what the `fc` was doing.
I will try and modify the `awk` code to extend it further.

Answer (score 0):

print the effective user-id (euid)

```
/bin/id -u
```